# escape quotes using sed in jenkins pipline sh step

Tags: groovy, sed, jenkins-pipeline

Need to insert variable value into sh step that using sed, but receive empty result
Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

def call(def cap_server){
    dir("ruby"){
        cap_server="pidor"
        sh '''bundle install'''
        sh '''sed -i "1i server '${cap_server}', user: 'ubuntu', roles: %w{web app db sidekiq}, ssh_options:{ keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa)}" config/deploy/qa.rb'''
        sh '''bundle exec cap qa deploy'''
    }
}
```

And here is the result:

```
+ sed -i 1i server '', user: 'ubuntu', roles: %w{web app db sidekiq}, ssh_options:{ keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa)} config/deploy/qa.rb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use double quotes to create a strong template

```
sh """sed -i "1i server '${cap_server}', user: 'ubuntu', roles: %w{web app db sidekiq}, ssh_options:{ keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa)}" config/deploy/qa.rb"""
```

Comment: it works well. that was quite obvious variant to use when triple single quotes  don't work. Thank you

Comment: Groovy has lots of different operators for constructing strings, each with different properties http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#all-strings